# How to setup another application from its setup file silently without any window(.exe)? c#

Tags: c#, winforms, installation, exe

How can i install another application through my windows form application? I have the setup file(*.exe) of the application that I want to install. I want the process to run silently and show a MessageBox when it gets completed successfuly.

Below is the code I have tried:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(checkBox1.Checked == true)
    {
        //samplep = Process.Start(@"run\msiexec.exe", "/norestart /i setup.msi");
        // Part 1: use ProcessStartInfo class.
        ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
        startInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
        startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        startInfo.FileName = @"E:\Test projects\desktop\dd\dd\Data\wrar521b1.exe";  //Enter the path to the setup file

        startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;

        // Part 2: set arguments.
        startInfo.Arguments = "-f j -o \"" + e + "\" -z 1.0 -s y " + e;

        try
        {
            // Part 3: start with the info we specified.
            // ... Call WaitForExit.
            using (Process exeProcess = Process.Start(startInfo))
            {
                exeProcess.WaitForExit();
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the setup file(.exe) of the application you want to install, you can easily do it this way:

```
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
psi.FileName = "Enter filepath here";//Enter the path to your setup file
psi.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
psi.RedirectStandardError = true;
psi.UseShellExecute = false;
psi.CreateNoWindow = true;

var process = new Process() ;
process.StartInfo = psi;
var handle = Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainWindowHandle;
Process.Start(psi).WaitForInputIdle();
SetForegroundWindow(handle.ToInt32());
process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
process.WaitForExit();

MessageBox.Show("Setup finished!");
```

This Google search might be useful:
How to run exe silently c#

**Edit:**

```
PowerShell powerShell = null;
try
                {
                    using (powerShell = PowerShell.Create())
                    {
                        //Enter the path to your setup file instead of 'filepath'                             

                        powerShell.AddScript("$setup=Start-Process 'filepath ' -ArgumentList ' / S ' -Wait -PassThru");


                        Collection<PSObject> PSOutput = powerShell.Invoke(); foreach (PSObject outputItem in PSOutput)
                        {

                            if (outputItem != null)
                            {

                                //MessageBox.Show(outputItem.BaseObject.GetType().FullName);
                                //MessageBox.Show(outputItem.BaseObject.ToString() + "\n");
                            }
                        }

                        if (powerShell.Streams.Error.Count > 0)
                        {
                            string temp = powerShell.Streams.Error.First().ToString();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("Setup finished!")
                        }                    
                    }
                }
catch (Exception err)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(err.ToString());
                }
                finally
                {
                    if (powerShell != null)
                        powerShell.Dispose();
                }
```

Comment: i add above code and didn't work with me
error in ex1 and ex2

Comment: @MohamedElSoufi: ex1 and ex2? Pls tell me the line no. where you get the error.

Comment: @MohamedElSoufi: I have edited the code and have also added another code. Pls try out both of them. Both of the codes work perfectly fine for me. Pls use the code that suites your need. Revert back if any error pops up.

Comment: `finally` block wrong/unnecessary.

Comment: @UweKeim:      It doesn't cause any problem, does it? The code works perfectly fine.